# Update the Local Computer Policy in Windows 7 with IGroupPolicyObject

Tags: c++, windows-7, group-policy, gpo

I just want to be able to programmatically do what `gpedit.msc` does. I'm trying to set the value of these keys to 1 and Update the Local Group Registry.

**In gpedit.msc:**

*Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/System/Removable Storage Access*

**ValueName:** All Removable Storage classes: Deny all access

**Value:** 1 (set this to 1)

*Local Computer Policy/Computer Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/AutoPlay Policies*

**ValueName**: Turn off Autoplay

**Value:** 1 ( set this to 1)

I think the key is to use `IGroupPolicyObject` in C++. However, I can't find any documentation that I can wrap my head around.

My application needs to disable/enable all USB Access without having to reboot Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that these links will help you:

- C/C++ with a fully described way to change a setting in LGPO: [Pete's Blog - Programatically setting and applying Local Group Policies on Windows](http://pete.akeo.ie/2011/03/porgramatically-setting-and-applying.html)
- C# code that alters LGPO object by ComImport mechanism [Software Developer's Bytes - Group Policy Object via .NET\C#](http://sdbytes.blogspot.com/2012/10/group-policy-object-via-netc.html)

Comment: Based on those links I wrote this .NET library to make things easier: https://bitbucket.org/MartinEden/local-policy