# Managing 'Security Settings' in Active Directory GPO using C++

Tags: c++, windows, gpo

Need help with modify 'Security Settings' in AD's GPO.

The 'Administrative template' settings are stored in corresponding ADMX files. I'm able to change these settings using `IGroupPolicyObject` in C++.

I couldn't find the actual storage of 'Security Settings' in Windows / Active Directory.

I am trying to get the list of settings along with any/all properties programmatically. Any leads are appreciated.

Please check the below screenshot as a reference to Security settings.

[image]

Comment: Is this useful by any means? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12926644/update-the-local-computer-policy-in-windows-7-with-igrouppolicyobject

Comment: Thank you @SantronManibharathi. But that is for Administrative template settings management. Am looking for other settings in GPO.